# Буферизация

Tags: php

Метод Code() срабатывает 2 раза, исправьте пожалуйста!

```
public function Form(){
        $exp = explode(',', $this->form);
        ob_start();
        for($i=0; $i<=count($exp)-1; $i++)
        {
            echo $exp[$i].' <input type="text" name="'.$i.'"><br>';
        }
        $this->content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        self::Show();
    } 
  public function Show(){
        ob_start();
        echo '<form action="" method="POST"';
        echo $this->content; 
        echo '<input type="submit" /><br>';
        $this->code = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        self::Code();
    }
    public function Code(){
       echo "Code:<br><textarea>".$this->code."</textarea>";
    }
```

**выкладываю весь свой класс**

```
class CreatForm {
    static $content;
/* Get the data with POST method
*  @string $form
*/  
    public function __construct($form){
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->content;
        $this->code;
    }
/* We share the data, we substitute them in input
*  the form itself put into the buffer
*  call the method Show for forming the structure of the form
*/ 
    public function Form(){
        $exp = explode(',', $this->form);
        ob_start();
        for($i=0; $i<=count($exp)-1; $i++)
        {
            echo $exp[$i].' <input type="text" name="'.$i.'"><br>';
        }
        $this->content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        self::Show();
    } 
/*
* The Form
*/ 
    public function Show(){
        ob_start();
        echo '<form action="" method="POST"';
        echo $this->content; 
        echo '<input type="submit" /><br>';
        $this->code = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        self::Code();
    }
    public function Code(){
        echo "Code:<br><textarea>".$this->code."</textarea>";
    }
}
/*
* 
*/ 
$form = new CreatForm($_POST['form']);
$form->Form();
```

**пишу сервис для быстрого создания web форм, вот остановился на первом классе, может подскажите другие реализации?**

Comment: @ReinRaus, [ну е-мое же](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-contents.php), она php-шная)

@johniek_comp, покажите вызов. По идее не должно быть такого. И название класса заодно (мало ли). Мне кажется, у вас где-то должен быть двойной вызов или вызов в конструкторе.

Comment: возвращает снимок буфера.

Comment: @FLK, скриншот, да.

Comment: Меня лично как то смущает, что после Show() тэги FORM и INPUT окажутся внутри TEXTAREA- это так и задумано ?

Comment: Вот так создаю экземпляр

$form = new CreatForm($_POST['form']);
$form->Form();

спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: вопрос решен, ошибка в логике была, не досмотрел

Comment: @johniek_comp вот и ладненько, вот и хорошо, я так понимаю не в этом куске кода дело было?

Comment: Вы не правильно всё сделали. Я про логику. Тут не нужна буферизация.

Comment: @exec Вам тоже не понравилось, что код, который можно выстроить в одну линию разбит на три функции в каждой из которых включается и отключается буферизация?

Comment: в методе show так надо было echo $this->code; self::Code();
а насчет кода, то я учусь, по этому делаю так что бы научится только, естественно тут пару строк процедурой :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы наверное, вот так хотели сделать?

```
echo '<form><input name="inputs" /></form>'; 
if(isset($_GET['inputs'])) {
    $inputs = $_GET['inputs'];
    $str = '<form method="post">';
    foreach(explode(',', $inputs) as $k => $v)
        $str .= $k . ' <input type="text" name="' . $v . '"><br>';
    $str .= '<input type="submit" /></form>';
    echo 'New form:<br>' . $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

чет либо я туплю либо лыжи не едут - скопировал запустил - результата двойного срабатывания метода Code() не наблюдаю(